# DictWriter writerow() not appending as expected

Tags: python, csv, append

I have this csv file:

unformatted_address,formatted_address,lat,lng
"3400 Main Street Prescott, Arizona 86303 United States","3400 Main Street Prescott, AZ 86303, USA",34.1234567,-112.7654321

The following code is intended to add a new row to the end of the csv file:

```
with open('Geocode_test.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['unformatted_address', 'formatted_address', 'lat', 'lng'])
    row = {'unformatted_address': '70 Orchard Ave Cancun New York 10555',
           'formatted_address': '70 Orchard Ave Cancun NY 10555 USA',
           'lat': 100.1,
           'lng': 200.2}
    writer.writerow(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
    csvfile.close()
```

I expected this result:

unformatted_address,formatted_address,lat,lng
"3400 Main Street Prescott, Arizona 86303 United States","3400 Main Street Prescott, AZ 86303, USA",34.1234567,-112.7654321
70 Orchard Ave Cancun New York 10555,70 Orchard Ave Cancun NY 10555 USA,100.1,200.2
70 Orchard Ave Cancun New York 10555,70 Orchard Ave Cancun NY 10555 USA,100.1,200.2

instead, I got this result:

unformatted_address,formatted_address,lat,lng
"3400 Main Street Prescott, Arizona 86303 United States","3400 Main Street Prescott, AZ 86303, USA",34.1234567,-112.765432170 Orchard Ave Cancun New York 10555,70 Orchard Ave Cancun NY 10555 USA,100.1,200.2
70 Orchard Ave Cancun New York 10555,70 Orchard Ave Cancun NY 10555 USA,100.1,200.2

Notice that the first `writerow()` seems to concatenate the first field to the last entry of the csv and then write the subsequent entries to columns to the right. The second `writerow()` behaves as expected.

Comment: Sorry...my "expected result" should have two identical new rows

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the actual expected result.

Comment: Why did you write `newline=''`? Have you considered that it has something to do with your problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 That's how it's supposed to be done, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3. The problem might be that the original csv lacked a final newline.

Comment: Thank you for providing your code as text. Please *do not post images*of your data*, though. That is really unhelpful. CSV is a text format -- *post the text*.

Comment: What's more, this seems to be a screenshot of some spreadsheet software (excel?). This makes it even more difficult to figure out what is going on. It **looks** like the csv you are opening does not have a newline at the end. The csv writer takes no responsibility for the state of the buffer you pass in as the argument. It just emits valid CSV.

Comment: i.e. you have the text `a,b,c|` with the `|`representing the cursor when you open in `"a"` mode. You then *write* `d,e,f` and end up with `a,b,cd,e,f`.

Comment: So, whatever the source of `'Geocode_test.csv'` is, it didn't do what most would consider to be the correct thing and end the text with a newline. (it probably wasn't done with the `csv` library, which will handle that for you)

Comment: I have edited my question as per mkrieger1 and juanma.arrivillaga requests. In doing so, I confirmed  @Thierry Lathuille idea that the original csv lacks a newline at the end of the file. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The original csv lacked a newline at the end of the file.